# libGDX Error FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: java, libgdx

This is the error I get from the console of the program and it won't let me even import the gradle to Eclipse

Generating app in C:\Users\mrgnh\Desktop\libGDXstuff
Executing 'C:\Users\mrgnh\Desktop\libGDXstuff/gradlew.bat clean --no-daemon'
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Settings file 'C:\Users\mrgnh\Desktop\libGDXstuff\settings.gradle'
- What went wrong:
  Could not compile settings file 'C:\Users\mrgnh\Desktop\libGDXstuff\settings.gradle'.

> startup failed:
> General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I am blind and that libGDX does not support JDK 16 only 8-15
So when creating the gradle with the JDK 16 gradle System it wasn't working out

Answer (score 0):

Try to change to latest [gradle website](https://gradle.org/releases/) version of gradle in file: **Gradle** -> **Wrapper** -> **gradle-wrapper.properties**

[image]

It helped me.